# When to use nullable columns - sql

Tags: sql

In specs default columns are set as nullable meaning they optional, I'm not clear what scenario is this good for to use with? I'll break it into two questions:

1. Why would I even want to use it in relational db? If integrity isn't important Ill use other half-structured model. Fearing for each row would it return usable object. Seems it is pretty rare scenario to use them in relational db.
2. Handling it in programing language. Is it even different in different languages? Let's say php, what values should it be compared with? fetch_array() are even keys going to be set?

Comment: Nullable types/fields are important and used in many data structures, not only Databases. Programming languages, like C# also implement nullable types. In a simple sentence, nullable fields represent OPTIONAL data placeholders. For example, consider creating user records for some hypothetical online forum: certain info can be set mandatory, like First/Last Name (thus, non-nullable fields required); other fields could be optional (for e.g. musical preferences, hobbies, etc.) Best regards,

Comment: I can think of two reasonable use-cases: 1. Optional fields - I need those pretty rare. 2. Single table inheriting strategy.

Comment: From answers below I can identify more: 3. Placeholders for values that will be known at later time, or generally that can be unknown in some moment. 4. Attributes of objects that are same type but not exactly same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A null value indicates an absent value--it's different from a zero-value (for numbers) or an empty value (for strings).  Think of a boolean column where a user opts true or false to a question--if the user hasn't yet completed the form then their response would be null.

In practice null is the default value for optional columns; it's also required that a new column being added allows nulls (at least until all records have been assigned a non-null value).

Most languages have specific support for null.  PHP can be a bit confusing as it's easy to ignore the differences between null, empty, false, and zero.  PHP will evaluate all of these as `false` if checked in a boolean statement--but they're all there and distinct.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` should be used when you legitimately don't have a value or when the value doesn't make sense.  `NULL` is good for "I don't know".

I'll use some examples from the system I use at work, a student information system.

In the registration table, there's a field for the first name, middle name, and last name of a student.  Leaving out some details, what do you do about students that don't put anything in the middle name field on the enrollment form?  They're implying they don't have a middle name, but that's not the same as explicitly writing "no middle name" in the field.  Using an empty string would be explicitly stating that they don't have a middle name.  The truth is, you don't know.  Use `NULL`.

In the entry/withdrawal table, each entry has one entry date, and one withdrawal date.  Now, when a student enters, the school has no idea when the student leaves.  It might be the end of the year.  It might be tomorrow.  It hasn't happened yet.  Use `NULL`.

Now, you can argue that any field which could be nullable should be in it's own table, but that level of normalization is basically unworkable for a real work application.  I mean, to get a student's name, you'd need to join four tables because that's three 1 to 0-1 relationships.  You're not even saving data space by doing this, since you have to store all those IDs somewhere to map everything back, *and* you have to index everything to make it work faster than a snail's pace.  You're sacrificing the usability of the DB on altar of normalization and the main thing you gain is a loss of performance.

First Normal Form is absolutely vital.  You'll see lots of questions here that boil down to, "Help! I violated 1NF and now queries are a huge pain in the ass!"  Second Normal Form is often a great idea.  Third Normal Form is when things often start to get unworkable or unreasonable for most non-trivial types of data.

Answer (score 0):

DEFAULT NULL columns are very common in actual applications.  You might not have values for all fields -- for example, if you have columns for name, email and phone, and no phone number was provided, storing NULL is perfect in that situation.

In php, fetch_array() will return all requested fields, those that are NULL will be set to the php `null` value.  You can test either for truthy `if ($value)` or if empty strings or zeroes are allowed, explicitly `if ($value !== null)`

Comment: "if empty strings or zeroes are allowed" - So it even depends of column type? Null from column can fetch as null, '', and 0 in php?

Comment: no no, NULL will always return `null` in php.  I was saying that some non-NULL data values will test the same as NULL when using the "truthy" test `if ($column)`, and an explicit null test must be used to distinguish.  In php, `0`, `0.0`, the empty string `""`, an empty array `array()`, `false` and `null` all test false.

Answer (score 0):

1. Primary keys in a relational DB cannot be null, and this grants your DB integrity. The others fields can be null depending on your design and logic. Sometimes you have optional fields and null is good for not valorized fields.
2. In PHP you can check mysql null values with [is_null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) function.